# Right click in Silverlight 3 *in* browser

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I'm surprised to notice that my right click code no longer works in-browser for Silverlight 3.  I think the problem could be that in SL2 I was using the asp Silverlight control and setting the property Windowless=true.  That control was removed in SL3 and now I'm using an object tag to display Silverlight content.  How can I get this to work again?  Code is:

```
ctor()
{
  HtmlPage.Document.AttachEvent("oncontextmenu", OnContextMenu);
}

public void OnContextMenu(object sender, HtmlEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Right click.");
  e.PreventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include in your object tags param list the following param:-

```
<param name="windowless" value="True" />
```

I'm surprised to here that the asp:silverlight control is gone?  Are you sure?

Comment: Oh yes, it's gone ;)  Check Tim Heuer's "what's new" post for more info.

Comment: @JC: So it is, interesting.  I'm somewhat skeptical of the "object is more flexible" reasoning though.